# Error while using python supprocess.call method ,

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

```
subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'call',
```

This is the error which i receive when i compile it in Linux, 
Here is the source code :

```
import subprocess
import sys
import random
import os


subprocess.call("exit 1", shell=True)
```

Comment: Perhaps you named one of your modules(or possibly current module) `subprocess.py`. Try printing `subprocess.__file__`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file or folder in the same directory with the name `subprocess`? It looks like you have not imported the correct core module.